# Left headlight turns off after starting car

Tags: chevrolet, headlight, wiring, malibu

### Issue

The left headlight on my 2005 Chevy Malibu seems to have a mind of its own.  It turns on when I unlock the car, and it also stays on for a bit when I shut the engine off and get out of the car, just like the other headlight.  But as soon as I start the car, the left headlight turns off.  It refuses to turn on as long as the engine is running.

### Attempted Repairs

I have replaced the bulb and the connector, but no results.  Which makes sense, clearly the bulb works, and it's getting power, because it works when the engine is off.  I don't think it could be the fuse or the wiring harness because, again, clearly the headlight is getting power.

### Questions

What could the issue be?  If it's something expensive or going to be hard to track down, could I just tape a flashlight to the side of the car to avoid being pulled over at night?  Does anyone have any tips on how to do so without sending a flashlight through the windshield of the car behind me on the interstate?  It's a POS car, so I really don't care about looks.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find the root of the issue, however, I was able to fix it.  What I ended up doing is tapping the fuse for the working headlight (in my case, the right headlight) and connecting it directly to the non-working headlight (in my case, the left headlight).

This would have been an easy task if I could use a fuse tap.  However, on the Chevy Malibu (and I'm sure many other cars), the headlight fuses are stuck between several tall relays, and a fuse tap just won't fit.  Here's how I made my own fuse tap:

1. I removed both headlight fuses.

> You can find which fuses are which in your car's owner's manual, or sometimes it's printed on the lid of the fuse box.

2. I took 2 short lengths of wire and stripped the ends.
3. I melted some solder onto one end of each wire to make them a bit thicker and stiffer.

> If you don't have a soldering iron, like me, you can use a butane torch to melt the solder.

4. I stuck the soldered tips into the right headlight fuse socket, so that both sides of the fuse socket now have a wire plugged into it.

> If the tips don't fit into the socket, or they're loose when you stick them in there, you may need to use more or less solder, or use a different gauge of wire.  It's really just a bit of trial and error.

5. I connected a fuse holder such that it connects the open ends of the 2 wires.
6. I connected another length of wire to the wire coming from the draw side of the fuse socket.  This is sort of a 3-way connection because the fuse holder is also connected.

> To determine which side is the draw side, turn the headlights on and use a multimeter to determine the voltage on each wire.  The wire with the positive voltage is the draw side.

7. I ran this new wire along the wiper fluid line up to the left headlight, using zip ties to hold the wire in place.
8. I connected another fuse holder to the end of the new wire.
9. I connected the new fuse holder to the left headlight wire.

> To determine which wire is the headlight wire, locate the wiring harness behind the headlight case.  Disconnect each wire one at a time and connect it to the battery positive terminal.  Only one should light up the headlight, and that is your headlight wire.

10. I put the correct size fuse into both fuse holders, and now both headlights should be connected.

> The correct fuse size is whatever was being used for the headlight fuses before you started messing with things.

I used soldered connections with heat shrink for protection for all 4 of the connections I mentioned above, but you can use whatever type of connection you like.

You may also need to cut a notch into the fuse box lid for the wires in order to get the lid to clip on all the way.

Both of my headlights work using this method.  I hope this can help someone else in the same position.